# Dúvidas sobre formatação de números hexadecimais em java para uso no MD5

Tags: java, formatação, md5

Eu gostaria de saber porquê o autor do artigo colocou essa parte:

```
senha = String.format("%1$032X", i);
```

Fiquei curiosa como ele conseguiu essa string: `"%1$032X"`

Segue o código completo:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MD5 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String senha = "photu5678";
        MessageDigest mensagem;

        try
        {
            mensagem = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            mensagem.update(senha.getBytes(), 0, senha.length());
            BigInteger i = new BigInteger(1, mensagem.digest());

            // Formatando o resultado em uma cadeia de 32 caracteres, completando com 0 caso falte 
            senha = String.format("%1$032X", i); 

            System.out.println("MD5: " + senha); 
        } 

        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta está na classe [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) que é utilizada pelo método [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

> - The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:
>
>   ```
>     %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
>   ```
>
>   The optional *argument_index* is a decimal integer indicating the position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by "`1$`", the second by "`2$`", etc.
>
>   The optional *flags* is a set of characters that modify the output format. The set of valid flags depends on the conversion.
>
>   The optional *width* is a positive decimal integer indicating the minimum number of characters to be written to the output.
>
>   The optional *precision* is a non-negative decimal integer usually used to restrict the number of characters. The specific behavior depends on the conversion.
>
>   The required *conversion* is a character indicating how the argument should be formatted. The set of valid conversions for a given argument depends on the argument's data type.

Traduzindo para o português:

> - Os especificadores de formato para tipos geral, caractere e numérico têm a seguinte sintaxe:
>
>   ```
>     %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
>   ```
>
>   O *argument_index* opcional é um inteiro decimal indicando a posição do argumento na lista de argumentos. O primeiro argumento é referenciado por "`1$`", o segundo por "`2$`", etc.
>
>   O *flags* opcional é um conjunto de caracteres que modifica o formato da saída. O conjunto de flags válido depende do *conversion*.
>
>   O *width* opcional é um inteiro decimal positivo indicando o número de caracteres mínimo a ser escrito na saída.
>
>   O *precision* opcional é um inteiro decimal não-negativo usualmente utilizado para restringir o número de caracteres. O comportamento específico depende do *conversion*.
>
>   O *conversion* requerido é o caractere indicando como o argumento será formatado. O conjunto de conversões válidas para um dado argumento depende do tipo de dado do argumento.

No caso do *conversion*, eis o que a classe `Formatter` especifica, entre outras coisas:

> `'x'`, `'X'`    The result is formatted as a hexadecimal integer

Traduzindo:

> `'x'`, `'X'`    O resultado é formatado como um inteiro hexadecimal

Segundo a documentação, os *conversions* maiúsculos produzirão a saída com letras maiúsculas e os minúsculos com letra minúscula.

Quanto ao *flags*:

> `'0'`    The result will be zero-padded

Traduzindo:

> `'0'`    O resultado será completado com zeros [à esquerda]

Ou seja, no caso de `"%1$032X"`, temos o seguinte:

- `%` indica que o texto que segue-se é um especificador de formato.
- `1$` é o *argument_index* que referencia o primeiro argumento da lista de argumentos (será o conteúdo da variável `i`).
- `0` é o *flags* que especifica que o número deve ser completado com zeros à esquerda.
- `32` é o *width*, ou seja, o comprimento do número. Ou seja, 32 caracteres.
- `X` é o *conversion*, que especifica que o número será expresso em dígitos hexadecimais, utilizando letras maiúsculas para os dígitos A-F.

Comment: Agora sim. Obrigada.